# time complexity of the following algorithm

Tags: big-o, binary-search-tree, logarithm

Suppose a Node (in a BST) is defined as follows (ignore all the setters/getters/inits).

```
class Node
{

     Node parent;
     Node leftChild;
     Node rightChild;
     int value;
     // ... other stuff
}
```

Given some a reference to some `Node` in a BST (called `startNode`) and another `Node` (called `target`), one is to check whether the tree containing `startNode` has any node whose `value` is equal to `target.value`.

I have two algorithms to do this:

**Algorithm #1:**

```
- From `startNode`, trace the way to the root node (using the `Node.parent` reference) : O(n)
- From the root node, do a regular binary search for the target : O(log(n))
```

T(n) = O(log(n) + n)

**Algorithm #2:** Basically perform a DFS
(Psuedo-code only)

```
current_node = startnode
While the root has not been reached  
     go up one level from the current_node
     perform a binary-search from this node downward (excluding the branch from which we just go up)
```

What is the time-complexity of this algorithm?

The naive answer would be `O(n * log(n))`, where `n` is for the `while` loop, as there are at most `n` nodes, and `log(n)` is for the binary-search. But obviously, that is way-overestimating!

The best (partial) answer I could come up with was:

- Suppose each sub-branch has some `m_i` nodes and that there are `k`
  sub-branches.
  In other words, `k` is the number of nodes between `startNode` and the root node
- The total time would be

.

```
T(n) = log(m1) + log(m2) + ... + log(mk)
     = log(m1 * m2 * ... * mk)
Where m1 + m2 + ... + mk = n (the total number of nodes in the tree)
```

(This is the best estimation I could get as I forgot most of my maths to do any better!)

---

**So I have two questions:**

```
0) What is the time-complexity of algorithm #2 in terms of n
1) Which algorithm does better in term of time-complexity?
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after digging through my old Maths books, I was able to find that the upper bound of a product of `k` numbers whose sum is `n` is `p <= (n /k) ^k`.

With that said, the `T(n)` function would become:

```
T(n) = O(f(n, k))
Where
f(n, k) = log((n/k)^k)
     = k * log(n/k)
     = k * log(n) - k * log(k)
```

(Remember, k is the number nodes between the startNode and the root, while n is the total number of node)

How would I go from here? (ie., how do I simplify the f(n, k)? Or is that good enough for Big-O analysis? )